# Safe submitting primary keys

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

I don't know how to program webpages very well so I have the following question. I have a MySQL database which a user can manage. I have two tables: persons, videos.

I want my page for the user to select a person from the persons table (by name for example) and then associate this person with a video link.
Selecting the person from database is easy,

```
SELECT personID, name
FROM persons
WHERE name LIKE '%John%'
```

So now the user has to insert a video link to the videos table which has a foreign key the personID.

I could store the primary key of the person after the "select" in a hidden html input form but I assume this is not very secure as they can edit it?

My question is: Where would you store such a key value in between a select and an insert call? 
Is it safer to store all this data in a session instead?

Comment: What if you have two John's in your Database, which is perfectly feasible?

Comment: He gets a drop down box including first and last name to select the correct one. But good point :)

Comment: Can the user edit the videos of every name?

Comment: Yes, I guess I would eventually need to keep track of who does what changes to catch bad guys messing around the database. In which case I guess it doesn't matter if he can change the personID in the html. But still, I want to know what the good form for this is

Comment: What about the case where you have John Smith, John Adams and Johnathon Blogs?  Your SQl will return them all!  Better to use a uniquely constrained field in your `persons` table, and select using a simple `=`.

Comment: Consider: `1.` Does it matter if people know the names of your primary keys? `2.` Does modifying this value mean they can do anything unintended to your database? If `2` is `true`, you will need to double check your server-side sanitisation of the input (which you should be doing anyway). If `1` is `true`, don't send the key to your client at all, save it in `$_SESSION` or elsewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sort of thing happens quite a lot, and it's *completely fine* as long as you don't mind people seeing your primary keys (if they're numbers, it shouldn't be anything to worry about).

Let's say you're retrieving a list of rows from a table, and displaying them in HTML. If you want each table row to have a 'delete' button for deleting that row, both from the DOM and in the Database, say via an XMLHttpRequest, it's typical for each row to have an "id" attribute, with the id being the primary key value of the row you wish to delete.

Typically, your primary key will be:

- The `id` field in your table
- The field with AUTO_INCREMENT set

In short, give each dropdown a `data-id` attribute, which you access in your JavaScript via the `.data` selector. That's good enough. Just make sure you're also protecting yourself from [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) and using PDO and prepared statements, and you'll be fine.

For extra protection, and to make sure nobody has altered the `data-id` attribute client-side before submit, check that the `id` corresponds to the `name` field in the database, and you're golden.

Comment: Well yes I guess I could just double check if the name matches the id. On the other hand, why keep the ID at all then. Might as well just `select` again the complete person name when he does the video `insert` and get the ID from the DB. I was thinking that this will lead to double the SQL queries (since I select the person twice) and might cause, dunno, performance problems maybe.

Comment: That's an architecture question, but MySQL is designed to handle thousands of queries - you'll have no measurable slow-down doing a check in one query before performing another. Rule #1 - don't prematurely micro-optimise :)

Comment: @Stefan Also, you keep the ID and name, and when they're POSTed through, you check both those against the rest of the table row to make sure they relate, and if so, they haven't been tampered with. You may not even need to do a double query, btw. If  you're updating, you just `UPDATE WHERE id = ?s AND name = ?s` etc.

Comment: No I am inserting to a different table so it's not an update. Thanks though, I think I will do it without the key. It's simpler and safe enough.

Answer (score 0):

I think storing this type of data in the session is **secure** and a good choice. After all, it's session-scoped, so there's no reason to output it. 
It would be more secure to store it in the session and, ofcourse, easier to access and manage.